# React SSR export default component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, server-side-rendering

I'm developing react js server side rendered application.I have `category.js` inside my `Home.js` and i want to do ssr for those two files as well.

**Home.js**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { connect } from "react-redux";
    import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
    import { loadMenuCategories } from "../actions/Home";
    import { component as Menu }  from './components/Menu';
    import { component as DefaultCategory } from './Category';

    class Home extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
            this.props.loadMenuCategories();
        }

     render() {
      const { categories, selectedCat } = this.props;
      return (
                <div >
                 <Menu/>
                 <DefaultCategory />
               </div >
      );
     }
     }
    }

    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch,ownProps) {

        return bindActionCreators({ loadMenuCategories}, dispatch);
    }

    function mapStateToProps({ categories }) {
        return { categories };
    }

   function loadData(Store,Props) { 
    return Promise.all([
        Store.dispatch( loadMenuCategories()) 
      ]);

   } 

    export default {
        loadData,
        component: connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home)
    };
```

**category.js**

```
import React, { Component, PureComponent } from 'react';
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import {CATS } from '../config';

class Category extends PureComponent {
  componentWillMount() {
        CATS.map(data => {
            this.props.fetchCategorySliders(data, LIMIT);
        });
    }
}

render() {
return (
            <div >
               .......
               ......
           </div >
  );
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({ fetchCategorySliders }, dispatch);
}

function mapStateToProps({ new_release, trending, editor, video_details,vStatus }) {
    return { new_release, trending, editor, video_details,vStatus };
}
function loadData(store, path) {
    return Promise.all([
        CATS.map(data => {
            Store.dispatch( fetchCategorySliders(data));
        })       
      ]);
}
export default {
    loadData,
    component: withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Category))
};
```

but i'm getting bellow error.

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string
>   (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: object.
>       in Home
>       in Connect(Home)
>       in Route
>       in Switch
>       in div
>       in App
>       in Route
>       in Switch
>       in div
>       in Router
>       in StaticRouter
>       in Provider (node:9310) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Invariant Violation:
>   Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Comment: how you are importing the component?
if you are writing import Category from './Category' then its wrong
you need to write import { component as Category } from './Category'
to use <Category />

Comment: @ArshpreetWadehra i have change the code as your suggestion,but got same error

Comment: are you using import DefaultCategory from './Category';
if so its wrong. see you are exporting an object containing loadData and component we need component either you use
<DefaultCategory.component /> or import {component} from './Category' and use <component />

Comment: no,i'm importing it like this `import { component as DefaultCategory } from './Category';`

Comment: you need to follow same pattern with Home also you are exporting home in similar pattern. I don't see loadData in Home.js

Comment: Sorry for my mistake and i have correct it.

Comment: ok my point is you are following same pattern everywhere for exporting {component: ...}, so you need to apply same import pattern too import {component } from '...';

Comment: i've eddited my code and used same pattern for `import` and `export`.then got this error `expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined`

Comment: try removing <Menu/>
                 <DefaultCategory /> and just console/debug Menu and DefaultCategory see what you are getting. if you got undefined
then change import statement to import Categroy from './Category' and console/debug Category see what you are getting

Comment: when i remove `<Menu/> <DefaultCategory /> `,project working fine

Comment: did you tried console Menu and DefaultCategory what actually you are getting?

Comment: when i remove `<Menu/> <DefaultCategory />` no console errors.project is working without menu and categories

Comment: I meant try console.log(Menu) & console.log(DefaultCategory) inside render() method to check exactly what you are importing

Comment: console log showing `ƒ C(props) {
    var wrappedComponentRef = props.wrappedComponentRef,
        remainingProps = _objectWithoutProperties(props, ["wrappedComponentRef"]);

    return __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_react___…`

Comment: Hi @ArshpreetWadehra and @Tje123 did you ever get to the bottom of this?
Having a similar issue with React / nextJS trying to import `react-ideal-image` but no amount of variations of importing styles seems to fix the `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.` error. Hellllllpppppp 